# How to find used memory on linux server in ssh

Tags: linux, ssh

I have a site which is a 1and1 dedicated Linux server.

It has the `/dev/mapper/vg-00-var` at a stupidly high, `148G` and is at `88%` which considering the actual website size is only `250MB` there is obviously something wrong.

I have looked with the server error logs on the ftp client and find no errors.

How do I find why the memory usage is so high using ssh?

Comment: Do you know a bit Linux? It could be worthwhile to install it on your laptop to learn it. I don't understand if you are concerned by disk space (use the `df` command to measure) or by memory (use the `free` command to measure). You question is off-topic on stackoverflow, because unrelated to source code.

Comment: And don't care about size of pseudo files under `/dev/mapper`

Answer (score 3):

Try typing in the command prompt

> top

To find out where the instance is type

> which instaceName

Like

> which ruby

Should give

> /etc/ruby

Or what not

Comment: And press the `q` key to quit the `top` display....

Comment: This is good but its not giving exact location, for instance error log has most of the hard drive memory etc

Comment: Most log files are under `/var/log/` and you could use the `find` command to find huge files.